# Should this Documentation review have been approved?

Tags: discussion, documentation, proposed-changes

I just started reviewing some Documentation changes, and I don't know how to review the following [documentation change](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/145723). I rejected it with "too specific", because the proposed change adds a lot of code. Normally I skip those, but they are always approved or rejected, without a clear indiction what the correct action should be.

I would say that examples should be as small as possible, so that readers can quickly see what they need, and not read through a lot of boilerplate code. It is especially bad because this is Java, and not say Python.

I would remove everything, just keeping the `send` function, removing unnecessary things (like the huge print statements) and adding a lot of comments and explanation outside. Maybe I would also break it up in multiple parts.

What is the correct action here?

Comment: It is not a change, it is new topic.  It needs to be only as expansive as necessary.  You can't realistically expect that goal to be reached at the very first attempt, somebody else can work on making it smaller.  That this tends to not happen is a very different kind of problem, but that needs to be addressed later.

Comment: Even Java examples can have the boilerplate code stripped from them. For Documentation, I'd prefer an example that has comments explaining the "how" and "why". Even if that makes the code longer.

Answer (score 4):

This should have been rejected as "too specific". But for somewhat different reasons than you mention.

It is posted in the "email" tag, but it is about a specific third-party API.
If that API had a tag of its own, it should have been posted there.
If the Documentation item was about the builtin email support of a language or framework, it should be posted under that language or framework.

**EDIT:**
It's even worse. The code snippets were [blatantly copy-pasted](https://github.com/Imaginatio/postmark-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/postmark/PostmarkMailSender.java). You were the only reviewer who was actually thinking, instead of mindlessly clicking <kbd>Approve</kbd>.

We should give the editor credit for adding some explanation of their own. But a significant part of the topic was copy-pasted. Hence the "copied content" Reject reason would still have been appropriate.